# GITHUB : I want to add project from local to live server through github

Tags: php, git, github, automation

I have project in php and I have to automate things.Currently,I have to upload a files manually to the cpanel via FTP or something else.Now,I have to do following:

**case 1 :** Create project into git repo let's call it - MasterProject (Main branch master)

**case 2 :** Create another branch in git call it - BetaProject

**Case 3 :** Cpanle www.mydomain.com is my website.I have live site currently here.

When I have to change i have to change in BetaProject Branch and after that I have to merge it with main branch (i.e. master),this means master is runnable  project ever.**When I merge Beta branch to master its automatically reflect into the website domain (i.e. www.mydomain.com).** How can I achieve this?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308535/automatic-prune-with-git-fetch-or-pull or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400043/automatically-pulling-on-remote-server-with-git-push or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132144/how-can-i-automatically-deploy-my-app-after-a-git-push-github-and-node-js

Comment: Hello,Can you please tell how can I achive this

Comment: Those answers are not satisfactory. Didn't work for me?

Comment: Didn't work for you how? What did you try?

Comment: Yes,there is lots answer say's create a hook "Push-Recived" but I do the same step by step still failed

Comment: Failed how? Did you really look at all the answers. I find it really hard to believe you can properly attempt all supplied answer in under 6 minutes tbh.

Comment: No,I am working on this from last 4 days that's why I have go through maximum things.